# Preserve spacing while using align with amsmath

Tags: amsmath, align

While

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
&   A \\
& = B
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

preserves the horizontal space after the equals sign,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  & A \\
= & B
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

gobbles this. Is there a way to preserve the space? 
(OK, in the MWE alignment could be placed behind A and B, but it is just a *minimal* example.)
If it is not: How wide *is* the space (as to use `\hspace{ something }`)?

Comment: Your two fragments are identical. did you post the wrong thing? (Also the `&` should be before the `=` in AMS alignments)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, my mistake, I just corrected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in order to be able to add the correct space, (la)tex needs to know exactly what precedes and follows the equals sign.  in this case, the `&` is "hiding" the letter that follows, so the space added is the default -- none.

in most cases, signs of relation are preceded and followed by "ordinary" characters (like letters).  you can emulate this situation in your example by adding an empty group -- `{}` before and/or after the equals sign:

```
{} = {} & B
```

this is actually overkill; only the group *after* the equals sign is needed, but the extra group doesn't hurt, and may make the intention more clear to a reader of the input.

if you are aligning on a character of some other class, the "correct" spacing is shown in a little table in the texbook, p.170.

Answer (score 3):

The AMS alignments are designed so that you use the `&` before not after the alignment operator, If you really can't do that for some reason using `{}={}` rather than `=` will ensure the equals sign gets the infix relation spacing.

Comment: OK, upvoted your answer (as well as BB's one), but because I do not know which one was given first (both labelled as "answered 1 hour ago"), and BB's answer is a little bit more extensive, I just accepted her answer. (With >50k reputation I hope this is no problem for you, but I just had to decide for one answer, sorry!)

Comment: Mine was first by a second or two but I've known @barbara a _long_ time and they are effectively her packages to look after so I don't begrudge her the green tick:-)

Comment: @Stephen OT: If you hover over "3 hours ago" you see the exact timestamp (in UTC).