# Long brackets in flalign*

Tags: math-mode, brackets

I'm trying to type a nice looking long sum of functions:

[image: example of what looks okay]

I managed to do it with combination of `flalign*` and `\mspace`:

```
\begin{flalign*}
f(a+h)-f(a)=&f(a_1+h_1,\dots\mspace{25mu}\dots,a_n+h_n)-f(a_1,\dots\mspace{120mu}\dots,a_n)=\\
=&f(a_1+h_1,a_2+h_2,\dots\mspace{1mu}\dots,a_n)-f(a_1,a_2,\dots\mspace{95mu}\dots,a_n)+\\
+&f(a_1+h_1,a_2+h_2,a_3,\dots,a_n)-f(a_1+h_1,a_2,\dots\mspace{55mu}\dots,a_n)+\\
&\dots\\
+&f(a_1+h_1,\dots\mspace{24mu}\dots,a_n+h_n)-f(a_1+h1,\dots,a_{n-1}+h_{n-1},a_n)\\
\end{flalign*}
```

I'm pretty happy with what I got, but here's my question: is it possible to make right brackets place themselves automatically in the right place? `\phantom` could help, if not for `a_n+h_n` instead of `a_n` bit. And is it possible to use another `&` pointer (say, `&2`), to mark the line of "-"s?

On the side note: how come this whole "reputation" does not allow me to make new tags? Aren't they suppose to, you know, HELP people?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  when you say you would like the right brackets "in the right place", can i assume you mean that you want them aligned vertically?  as a side note for you, you'd get better spacing if you put the `&` *before* equals signs and pluses, and add `{}` before any plus that begins a line and after any plus that ends a line.  for some reasons, look at the answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76423/preserve-spacing-while-using-align-with-amsmath/76426).

Comment: Concerning your side note: as I thought about answering it but couldn't find a really satisfying answer, I put it onto meta: [Why is a certain reputation needed to create new tags?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2799/why-is-a-certain-reputation-needed-to-create-new-tags)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

You need to put the `&` before the `+`  or `=` not after  otherwise you do not get the correct spacing, note your image has operators without infix spacing at both ends, I think you just want more alignment points.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
f(a+h)-f(a)&=f(a_1+h_1,\dots&\dots,a_n+h_n)&-f(a_1,\dots&\dots,a_n)={}\\
&=f(a_1+h_1,a_2+h_2,\dots&\dots,a_n)&-f(a_1,a_2,\dots&\dots,a_n)+{}\\
&+f(a_1+h_1,a_2+h_2,a_3,&\dots,a_n)&-f(a_1+h_1,a_2,\dots &\dots,a_n)+{}\\
&\dots\\
&+f(a_1+h_1,\dots&\dots,a_n+h_n)&-f(a_1+h1,&\dots,a_{n-1}+h_{n-1},a_n)\phantom{{}+{}}\\
\end{flalign*}
`



\end{document}
```

Comment: That is brilliant. Thanks for commenting on position of &, i thought it need to be after + or = or whatever, sothat the place s with "&"s are in line.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that this is a particularly nice way to express your thought.

However, this is one way that requires only to guess the widest vector, which can be done at a first stage. This is surely easier than guessing many spacings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newlength{\providewdlen}
\newcommand{\providewd}[2]{
  \settowidth{\providewdlen}{$\displaystyle#1$}
  \makebox[\providewdlen][s]{$\displaystyle#2$}
}
\newcommand{\alignplus}{\mathrel{\providewd{=}{\hfill+}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
f(a+h)-f(a)
 &= 
    f(\providewd{a_1+h_1,a_2+h_2,\dots\dots,a_n}{a_1+h_1,\dots\hfill\dots,a_n+h_n})
   -f(\providewd{a_1+h1,\dots,a_{n-1}+h_{n-1},a_n}{a_1,\dots\hfill\dots,a_n})\\
 &=
    f(\providewd{a_1+h_1,a_2+h_2,a_3,\dots,a_n}{a_1+h_1,a_2,\dots\hfill\dots,a_n})
   -f(\providewd{a_1+h1,\dots,a_{n-1}+h_{n-1},a_n}{a_1,a_2,\dots\hfill\dots,a_n})\\
 &\alignplus
   f(a_1+h_1,a_2+h_2,a_3,\dots,a_n)
  -f(\providewd{a_1+h1,\dots,a_{n-1}+h_{n-1},a_n}{a_1+h_1,a_2,\dots\hfill\dots,a_n})\\
 & \dots\\
 &\alignplus
   f(\providewd{a_1+h_1,a_2+h_2,a_3,\dots,a_n}{a_1+h_1,\dots\hfill\dots,a_n+h_n})
  -f(a_1+h_1,\dots,a_{n-1}+h_{n-1},a_n)
\end{align*}


\end{document}
```

Notice that the symbols should not to be repeated at the end of the lines and that `&` goes *before* the alignment point. There should *not* be a trailing `\\` in alignment environments.

Since the `+` is less wide than the `=`, we need to take care of that too. Note also that `flalign*` does nothing more than `align*` in this case; the differences can be seen when there is more than one alignment point.

[image]

My feeling is that a simpler approach could be clearer:

```
\begin{align*}
f(a+h)-f(a)
 &=f(a_1+h_1,\dots,a_n+h_n)-f(a_1,\dots,a_n)\\
 &=
   f(a_1+h_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)-f(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)\\
 &\alignplus
   f(a_1+h_1,a_2+h_2,a_3,\dots,a_n)-f(a_1+h_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)\\
 & \dots\\
 &\alignplus
   f(a_1+h_1,\dots,a_n+h_n)-f(a_1+h_1,\dots,a_{n-1}+h_{n-1},a_n)
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Notes:**

- I used the `scrartcl` class only because your original equation was to wide for the standard `article` class.
- [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) provides the `\math?lap` family and `\vdotswithin`.
- I removed one of `\dots` if they are followed without space.
- `\hphantom` intends the equations so that the second part is better aligned.
- I used the `alignat*` environment because for one equation the `flalign*` environment doesn't do much. (There is of course no `flalignat` environment.)
- I also removed `=` and `+` at the end of rows because I don't think that they make any sense there.

### Code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{4}
f(a+h)-f(a) & = f(a_1 + h_1, \dots                             & \mathllap{\dots, a_n + h_n)} & {} - f(a_1, \dots          & \dots, a_n)   \\
            & = \hphantom{{}+{}} f(a_1 + h_1, a_2 + h_2,       &           \dots, a_n)        & {} - f(a_1, a_2, \mathrlap{\dots}     & \dots, a_n)   \\
            & \hphantom{{}={}} + f(a_1 + h_1, a_2 + h_2, a_3,  &        {} \dots, a_n)        & {} - f(a_1+h_1, \mathrlap{a_2, \dots} & \dots,a_n) \\
            & \hphantom{{}={}} \vdotswithin{+} \\
            & \hphantom{{}={}} + f(a_1+h_1,\dots               & \mathllap{\dots, a_n + h_n)} & {} - f(a_1+h_1,{} & \dots, a_{n-1}+h_{n-1},a_n)\\
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]