# Difference in horizontal spacing between &= and =& in align

Tags: spacing, align

I just came along the situation that the horizontal spacing in an `align` environment is different depending on the position of the ampersand with relation to an equal sign (only checked for this case):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
A =& B
\end{align}
\begin{align}
A &= B
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The results looks like this:

[image]

Could someone please explain why there is a difference in spacing between the `=` and the `B`? is there a way to achieve the larger spacing when using `=&`? I need to have it this way, if I want to align a formula that needs a linebreak.

Thanks,
H2

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). The second example is the correct usage.  It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that shows the specific problem you are having.

Comment: Try with `={}&`.

Comment: When using `align`, there is an implied `{}` following the `&`.

Comment: @Peter Grill: Thanks for the nice welcome. The posted code actually contains a `\documentclass` and should work to create a PDF.

Comment: @user114854: Yes, you had posted complete example (which is a great start), but it did not show the mentioned problem of needing the `=&` to _align a formula that needs a linebreak_.

Comment: potential duplicate: [Preserve spacing while using align with amsmath](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76423)